# blank page when using the use keyword in php

Tags: php

I think I'm missing something guys and I'm a beginner.
I'm trying to build a website which includes uploading a 100k lines of excel and processing them and I've tried some libraries but with no luck, the box/spout sounds appealing with all the positive reviews it has so here is my problem.
I've installed composer on the same folder my my project, installed spout and got the vendor folder which contains box and spout. 
the problem is when ever I use the `use` keyword to test the reader I get a white blank page on my website.

I tried changing the use command to :

```
use vendor\box\spout\src\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
```

But with no luck.

Removing the `use` word give a fatal error obviously. Can you guys point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: check your server logs!

Comment: Turn on error reporting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: have you tried to import only the ReaderFactory without full path?

Answer (score 2):

the namespace of ReaderFactory is actually: `Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory`

you can also use the object directly without "use":

```
\Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory::create('csv');
```

Comment: Also worth noting that unless you have an autoloader, you will need to call `require("vendor/box/spout/src/Spout/Reader/ReaderFactory.php");` (or whatever the path/file may be)

Comment: The spout manual states that if composer is used I don't need to 'require' anything.

Comment: I tried both these two below but didn't work.
I'm getting "Fatal error: Class 'vendor\Box\Spout\Common\ReaderFactory' not found in "
$reader = \Box\Spout\Common\ReaderFactory::create('XLSX'); // for XLSX files
and $reader = \vendor\box\spout\src\Spout\Common\ReaderFactory::create('XLSX'); // for XLSX files

Comment: since you use composer do you include the autoload file of composer? the file should be in vendor/autoload.php

Comment: You still need to import the autoload.php file generated by Composer when you installed Spout. You should do it in your top-level controller

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I misplaced the "namespace" keyword putting it inside the function rather than the very top of the file. it all worked out when I moved it.